# display correct wind chill output for the converted Celsius to Fahrenheit means for elif user_scale=="C":

Tags: python, string, function, integer

Look carefully to elif statement, how to correctly connect it to the converted value of celcius to do calculations of wind chill, so it turned out as in output example

```
 celcius = 0
 
 
 def get_scale (temperature):
     celsius = (temperature * 9/5) + 32
     return celsius
 
 temperature = float(input("What is the temperature? "))
 user_scale = input("Farenheit or Celsius (F/C)? ")

 def get_wind_chill(temperature, speed):
     wind_chill = 35.74 + (0.6215 * temperature)  - (35.75 * (speed ** 0.16))  + (0.4275 * temperature * (speed ** 0.16))
     return wind_chill
     
 user_scale = user_scale.capitalize()
 for speed in range(5 , 65, 5):
     if user_scale == "F":
         wind_chill = get_wind_chill(temperature, speed)
         print(f"At temperature {temperature}F, and wind speed {speed}mph, the wind chill is: {wind_chill:.2f}F")
     elif user_scale == "C":
         celcius = get_scale(temperature)
         wind_chill = get_wind_chill(temperature, speed)
         print(f"At temperature {celcius}F, and wind speed {speed}mph, the wind chill is: {wind_chill:.2f}F")
```

the example of the output that is needed for converted Celcius (correct windchill output):

```
What is the temperature? -10
Fahrenheit or Celsius (F/C)? C
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 5 mph, the windchill is: 5.93F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 10 mph, the windchill is: 1.42F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 15 mph, the windchill is: -1.47F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 20 mph, the windchill is: -3.63F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 25 mph, the windchill is: -5.38F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 30 mph, the windchill is: -6.85F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 35 mph, the windchill is: -8.13F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 40 mph, the windchill is: -9.27F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 45 mph, the windchill is: -10.29F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 50 mph, the windchill is: -11.22F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 55 mph, the windchill is: -12.07F
At temperature 14.0F, and wind speed 60 mph, the windchill is: -12.87F
```

Comment: You do `celcius = get_scale(temperature)`, but then you pass `temperature` to `get_wind_chill`, not `celcius`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `if`/`elif`.  If they enter Celsius, just convert that to Fahrenheit and do the computation normally:

```
for speed in range(5 , 65, 5):
    if user_scale in "Cc":
        temperature = get_scale(temperature)
    wind_chill = get_wind_chill(temperature, speed)
    print(f"At temperature {temperature}F, and wind speed {speed}mph, the wind chill is: {wind_chill:.2f}F")
```

Comment: A typo was made in the original question as the `f string` should have temperature C  if using Celcius. Your code just needs another variable to vary the character C or F.

Comment: That's certainly another option.